# Database backup best practices

Tags: database-backup

For my current project, I'm using Aurora RDS and I'm looking for some advice on best practices in terms of backing up the database.  My thought is to use AWS Backup to backup the database to 3 separate locations (one in the West Coast, US, one in the East Coast, US, and one in Europe) and keep the backups for 30 days.  Is this a responsible backup strategy or should I have additional safeguards in place?

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. You need to be thinking about _restoring_. What circumstances would require you to restore? How long can your service be down while restoring?

Comment: I would need to restore if there's either some sort of database failure on Amazon's end or if at the application level I do something *really* bad (meant to delete one entry not *all* entries).  In terms of being down, while it would be annoying to my users for it to be down, this isn't a "critical system" application.  If it ever down for a few hours (or even up to 12 hours), the consequences wouldn't be catastrophic.